# Creating custom vertical UISlider

Tags: ios, customization, uislider

I've searched a lot, most people like this code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

[super viewDidLoad];

CGAffineTransform trans = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI * 0.5);
slider.transform = trans;
```

}

But for me it creates only thumb, why is it so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sanity check the slider.value after you transform. The slider will disappear when you have improper value set for it.

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
slider.layer.transform = trans;
```